# Multiple letter symbols in sympy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy, symbols

I would like to use a symbolic variable y[1] in sympy. In jupyter the last 3 characters of the symbol are displayed as subscript when using display. When using print it looks fine. So is there a way to avoid the subscripting of the variable.

```
  import sympy as sy

  y=sy.Symbol('y[1]')
  display(y*(y+1) )
  print( y*(y+1) )
```

Comment: I cannt reproduce the issue, both (`IPython.display.display`) "print"s _y[1]_. Could you clarify?

Comment: You are right. I used also import lcapy as lc which seems to be responsible for that. Deleting that works now. thanks.